# perl - printing hash variable values gives ARRAY(xxxxxxx)

Tags: arrays, perl, hash

I have two arrays of the following form:

```
root rhino root root root root root root root root root root domainte root
stam rhino jam onetwo domante ftpsi jay testwp contra raul vnod foos raul bruce
```

Using [help I got from SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19544309/perl-creating-a-hash-from-two-arrays), I have put both of them into a hash like so:

```
my %hash;
for my $idx (0 .. $#test2) {
push @{ $hash{ $test2[$idx] } }, $test3[$idx];}
print "<br /><br /><br /><br />";
print Dumper \%hash;
```

which gives the following output:

```
$VAR1 = { 'rhino' => [ 'rhino' ], 
          'domante' => [ 'raul' ],
          'root' => [ 'stam', 'jam', 'onetwo', 'domante', 'ftpsi', 
                      'jay', 'testwp', 'contra', 'raul', 'vnod', 
                      'foos', 'bruce' ] 
        };
```

Now push the key and values to 2 arrays like so:

```
my @q1 = keys %hash;
 my @q2 = values %hash;

 print "<br /><br /><br /><br />";
 print @q1;
 print "<br /><br /><br /><br />";
 print @q2;
```

While printing, I get the keys right, but the values print the following output:

```
ARRAY(0x9bf0b0)ARRAY(0x9bf1e8)ARRAY(0x9bf068)
```

How do I get all the values into arrays? What am I doing wrong?

Edit:

Here's what I tried:

```
foreach (@q1)
{       print @{$hash{$q1}};
        print "<br />";
}
```

but got no viable result.

Comment: Is your hash called `%hash` or is it called `%owners`?

Comment: @mob - %hash - that was a typo. Corrected. Sorry

Comment: You get no viable result because `$_` is the index of the `foreach` loop, not `$q1`. (Are you using `strict` and `warnings`?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The values of your hash are all *array references*. You can tell from the `Data::Dumper` output because all the values are enclosed in `[ ... ]` brackets. To print out the array's contents, you'll need to dereference the array references.

There are a lot of ways to do that. Here's a concise way that you can modify for your needs:

```
print "@$_\n" for @q2;
```

`$_` is an alias to an element of `@q2`, which you'll recall is an array reference. The expression `@$_` dereferences the reference, returning the array. Putting `@$_` in double quotes will print every element of the array with a space between the elements.

Comment: Thx for the quick answer. How would I go about printing such that values for each key is on a separate line?

Comment: As alternatives, you could locally adjust the array output separator before printing the array i.e. `local $" = "\n";`. Otherwise join the array i.e. `print (join "\n", @$_);`. Replace `\n` with `<br />` if working with HTML.